# Building a sitemap using python

Tags: python

Trying to build a site map using python

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

pages = set()
def getLinks (pageUrl):
  global pages
html = urlopen("http://www.mysite.ch" + pageUrl )
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for link in bsObj.findAll("a",href = re.compile(" ^ (/f/)" )):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
            newPage = link.attrs['href']
            print(newPage)
             pages.add(newPage)
                getLinks(newPage)
```

getLinks("")

I got the following error msg:

```
 File "sitemap builder.py", line 8, in <module>
  html = urlopen("http://www.mysite.ch" + pageUrl )
  NameError: name 'pageUrl' is not defined
```

If somepeople got ideas youre are welcome (sorry for bad indentation i agree it's not good)

Comment: Is this the full error trace?

Comment: are you sure thats the complete error message? that does not seem like its the complete error message

Comment: @GerriePretorius full error trace now in, sorry

Comment: @MrPyCharm full error trace now in, sorry

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. You need to correctly indent your code for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's assume that the code snippet you posted is correct and is indeed correctly formatted. Then, looking at line 8, where you have the error, clearly shows that

```
pageUrl
```

is in global scope, whereas it has been declared in the scope of

```
def getLinks (pageUrl):
```

Either you need to declare pageUrl or you need to properly format your code.